# Implementing Angular draggable droppable, how can I drop a DIV at a place and it stays there

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am using https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-draggable-droppable/demo/

I am able to drag my Div's which are seen in the below image, what I want is, if I drag `DIV 3` on `DIV 1` then `DIV 3` should sit in its place and other DIVs should slide down.

[image]

My `dragdrop.component.ts` code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {DragAndDropModule} from 'angular-draggable-droppable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dragdrop',
  templateUrl: './dragdrop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dragdrop.component.css']
})
export class DragdropComponent implements OnInit {
droppedData: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  dragEnd(event) {
    console.log('Element was dragged', event);
  }

}
```

and my `dragdrop.component.html` code:

```
<br><br>
<div mwlDraggable (dragEnd)="dragEnd($event)">Drag DIV  1</div>
<br><br>
<div mwlDraggable (dragEnd)="dragEnd($event)">Drag DIV  2</div>
<br><br>
<div mwlDraggable (dragEnd)="dragEnd($event)">Drag DIV  3</div>

    <div

      (drop)="this.droppedData = $event.dropData">

      <span [hidden]="!droppedData">Item dropped here with data: "{{ droppedData }}"!</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please look into this example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draggable-droppable-example1

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a very convenient plugin of Angular Material named `cdk` to implement `drag & drop` application.

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Hope this helps.